# c++ continued fractions output error

Tags: java, c++, c++14

I have written this Java code that works very well:

```
static String getFraction(double x) {
        double limit = 1.0E-6;     
        double h1 = 1, h2 = 0, k1 = 0, k2 = 1;
        double y = x;

        do {

            double a = Math.floor(y);
            double aux = h1;
            h1 = a*h1+h2;
            h2 = aux;
            aux = k1;
            k1 = a*k1+k2;
            k2 = aux;
            y = 1/(y-a);

        } while (Math.abs(x-h1/k1) > x*limit );

        return ((int) h1) + "/" + ((int) k1);  
    }
```

It takes a double (6.45) and returns its fractional representation using continued fractions (129/20). This is the C++ code:

```
 void calc(double x) {

    double limit = 1.0E-6;     
    double h1 = 1, h2 = 0, k1 = 0, k2 = 1;
    double y = x;

    do {

        double a = floor(y);
        double aux = h1;
        h1 = a*h1+h2;
        h2 = aux;
        aux = k1;
        k1 = a*k1+k2;
        k2 = aux;
        y = 1/(y-a);

    } while (abs(x-h1/k1) > x*limit );

    std::cout << (h1) << "/" << (k1) << std::endl;  
 }
```

The C++ translation is in my opinion identical to the Java version. The problem is this output:

```
Java (input 6.45) --> 129/20
C++ (input 6.45) --> 6/1
```

Any idea? Do I have to static cast something to double to allow floating point operations?

Comment: The fact is that I produced a C++ version first and I "wasted" a lot of time. Then I tried with Java and it worked. I can't understand where I am wrong in the C++ part!

Comment: Have you stepped through the code using a debugger during execution?

Comment: If I put a "cout << y" after "y = 1/(y-a);" it stops immediatly after 1 loop. This is weird and it's what is surprising me

Comment: I'm guessing the difference is due to the difference in floating point formats between Java and your C++ implementation. But that isn't really an answer. There's a distinguished user on SO, who is fond of Birmans, that may hopefully answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `abs()` function. I have had a similar problem in the past. Look at this code:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << abs(-85.5) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is 85. You have two solutions:

1. use `fabs()`
2. do a workaroud:

Something like this

```
double c;

do {

  double a = floor(y);
  double aux = h1;
  h1 = a*h1+h2;
  h2 = aux;
  aux = k1;
  k1 = a*k1+k2;
  k2 = aux;
  y = 1/(y-a);

  if ((x-h1/k1) >= 0)
    c = x-h1/k1; 
  else
    c = -(x-h1/k1);

} while (c > x*limit );
```

Answer (score 2):

The [abs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) function returns an `int` which will be `0`. You want to either use [fabs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fabs) or [std::abs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs), the latter has overloads for both integral and floating point types.

Comment: What, pray tell, could be anyone's reason for downvoting this?

Comment: @StoryTeller: I didn't, but IMHO this answer is wrong. `std::abs(double)` returns double. `std::abs(int)` returns int. OP clearly passes double.

Comment: @Jaa-c - `std::abs` does, `::abs` doesn't. Look at the OP's code. I'm quite certain they included `math.h` and not `cmath`.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Oh, I missed that.

Comment: The `std::` prefixes were added by an editor and made the answer incorrect, I've just removed them